# Modular Arithmetic proof? Every integer n can be written as $n=a^2 b$, where $b$ is a product of primes

Tags: modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

Every positive integer $k$ can be written as $k = m^2 n$ (where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers) and $n$ is a product of distinct primes that could be empty)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Proper formatting is expected also in the title.

Comment: This is fundamental theorem of airthmetic, just put $m=1$.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare OP probably meant "product of distinct primes", so that this is the standard fact that any number can be factored into square and squarefree parts.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to see this is by induction. It's true for $1$; assume it's true for all numbers below $k$.

If $k$ is not divisible by the square of a prime, then it must be a product of different primes, so $k=1^2k$ works. Otherwise $p^2$ divides $k$ for some prime $p$. But then $k=p^2j$ for some $j<k$, and by assumption $j=a^2b$ where $b$ is a product of primes. Then $k=(ap)^2b$.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1$, choose $m=n=1$

Otherwise $$k=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$$

with primes $p_1,\cdots p_n$ and positive integers $a_1\cdots a_n$

Collect the primes with odd exponent and let $P$ be the product of the primes. If no such prime exists , set $P=1$. Then, $\frac{k}{P}$ is a perfect square and we have the desired representation.

Comment: If no prime with odd exponent exists, we have the empty product $P=1$. In this case, the number $k$ is already a perfect square. Otherwise we divide out every prime with odd exponent. This leads to even exponents and therefore a perfect square. Note that all exponents might be $1$. In this case, we will have $m=1$ and $k=n$ ; $k$ is already squarefree.